# Hi, I have problems to make proj4string projection(raster())

Tags: r

I have problems to make proj4string  projection(raster())
MY CODE WAS AS THIS

```
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(dismo)
library(mapview)
lan <- r3_xls
head(lan)
coordinates(lan) <- ~lon + lat 
class(lan)
head(lan)
bio <- raster::getData('worldclim', var="bio", res="10")
library(usdm)
v1 <- vifstep(bio)
v2 <- vifcor(bio, th=0.9)
v1
v2
biom <- exclude(bio, v2)
plot(biom[[1]])
points(lan)
points(lan, cex=0.5, pch=16)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, xlim=c(65,70), ylim=c(38,39), axes=TRUE,
     col="light yellow")
points(lan, cex=0.5, pch=16)
R> area_lan <- sf::read_sf("uzb.shp")
R> tm_shape(area_dnipro) + tm_polygons()
proj4string(lan) <- projection(raster())
```

Then I got such warning
Warning message:

```
*In proj4string(obj) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output; in tests, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/CRS_warnings.html*
```

can somebody help me?